# Why does $(a_0I +a_1 T + \dots + a_n T^n ) v = c(T - r_1 I) \dots (T - r_m I) v$ imply that $T - r_j I$ is not injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, linear-transformations

I was reading [down with determinants](http://www.axler.net/DwD.html) and it had the equation:

$$(a_0I +a_1 T + \dots + a_n T^n ) v = c(T - r_1 I) \dots (T - r_m I) v = 0$$

from which it it concluded that $T - r_j I$ is not injective i.e. non-injective meaning that it does NOT preserve distinctness in the mapping i.e. there is some collision in the mapping. I have a couple questions:

1. The first issue that I am having is that I don't even know what things we are mapping and what is the mapper. i.e. what are the sets we are relating, what is the non-injection over what what does $T,r_i, a_i, c, v$ all have to do with this injection?
2. Also, probably related to my confusion, what theorem is he using to make a relation of the polynomial $a_0 + a_1 z + \dots a_n z^n = c(z - r_1) \dots (x - r_m)$ to linear operators. Why is that equation applicable to doing  $(a_0I +a_1 T + \dots + a_n T^n ) v = c(T - r_1 I) \dots (T - r_m I) v$ and what is its relation to this non-injectivness?

---

For the sake making the answer self contained here is the theorem I am trying to understand:

Theorem 2.1 Every linear operator on a finite-dimensional complex vector space
has an eigenvalue (Note: he defines one page before an eigenvalue as: A complex number $λ$ is called an eigenvalue of $T$ if $T −λI$ is not injective ).

Proof. To show that $T$ (our linear operator on V ) has an eigenvalue, fix any non- zero vector $v \in V$ . The vectors $v, T v, T^2v, \dots , T^nv$ cannot be linearly independent, because V has dimension $n$ and we have $n + 1$ vectors. Thus there exist complex numbers $a0,...,an$, not all $0$, such that
$$a_0 v + a_1 T v + · · · + a_n T^n v = 0 .$$
Make the a’s the coefficients of a polynomial, which can be written in factored form as
$$a_0 +a_1z+···+a_nz^n =c(z−r1)...(z−rm),$$
where $c$ is a non-zero complex number, each $r_j$ is complex, and the equation holds for all complex z. We then have
$$ 0 = (a_0I +a_1T +···+a_nT^n)v
= c(T −r_1I)...(T −r_mI)v ,$$
which means that $T − r_jI$ is not injective for at least one $j$. In other words, $T$ has
an eigenvalue.

Comment: Note the assumption is $0=(a_0I +a_1 T + \dots + a_n T^n ) v $ and the conclusion is that $T-r_jI$ is not injective *for at least one* $j$.

Comment: @Pin If you leave out the super important **given condition** that the left side of your equation equals zero, as Thomas says, the claim is not only false but rather hard even to understand.

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry that was probably a typo. Regardless sorry for being dense, but I still don't understand what the injection is even with the equal zero included.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews first sorry for the typo (missing the = 0) and yes, that is exactly the line I don't understand. Sorry if its super simple, I just don't see why that completes the proof. Is it because we have $(T - r_j I) v = 0 $ for more than one $r_i$? Or what makes the argument make sense?

Comment: @Pinocchio I added an answer that'll hopefully clear some things out.

Answer (score 2):

We're given

$$\left(a_0I+a_iT+\ldots+a_nT^n\right)v=c\left(T-r_1I\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot(T-r_mI)v$$

... **for a non-zero vector** $\;v\in V\;$ . Try to see it the following way: suppose $\;A_1,...,A_m\;$ are operators/square matrices s.t for a vector $\;0\neq v\in V\;$ we have

$$A_1\cdot\ldots\cdot A_m v=0\implies A_1\cdot\ldots\cdot A_m\;\;\text{ is a singular operator/matrix}\implies$$

at least one of $\;A_i\;$ is singular, as we know that the product of regular operators/matrices is again regular.

In our case, we get that at least one of $\;T-r_iI\;$ is singular $\;\iff r_i\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;T\;$ , and we're done, and in finite dimension singular $\;\iff\;$ non-injective.

Comment: that does make sense, I think (since some non zero maps to zero and obviously zero maps to zero so there is a collision so its non-injective). Also, it seems the author avoids ever making references to a matrices. Do you think that was that on purpose? Does that add anything to the proof or is it just to seem fancy?

Comment: @Pinocchio There no *real* need to mention matrices at all. I added the name because I can't know how you people study this stuff, but it is as easy with operators as with matrices.